# Capitalize first letter of a filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, dos, batch-rename

I have some files in a folder and would like to uppercase the first letter of all the filenames with a certain extension using a batch script in windows.

*example cap only* *.m

**before:**

- foo.m
- bar.m
- picture.jpg

**after:**

- Foo.m
- Bar.m
- picture.jpg

Comment: Are you able/willing to use PowerShell instead to script this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for %%a in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
 ren %%a*.m %%a* >nul 2>&1
)
```

Check also this -> https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards

Comment: +1, Very nice, but I liked your original better. Also, the OP has a filter of `*.m`. This simpler form should work: `for %C in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do @ren %C*.m %C*`

Comment: Yes.Thanks.Will fix this